# How to do unique count with grep and wc together?

Tags: cut, wc

```
cut -f1 test.csv | wc -l
```

I want to get the first column of the file, and do a unique count.

Where can I add a 'sort u' to make it count unique lines only?

Comment: What are the contents of test.csv?

Comment: Regular text file, with several columns. All are strings @Paolo